# How to disable specific dates in angular material datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

How can I disable specific dates based on the current date, let's say that today is 8/1/16, I want to disable 4 days (4 it's an example it could be any number) after the current date weekends days doesn't count,

Example if today is 8/1/16 I want to disable  8/2/16 , 8/3/16, 8/4/16 and 
8/5/16, and the dates that would be available would be the ones that are after 8/8/16.

At the moment I only know how to disable all the weekend days in the calendar with this filter

```
$scope.disableSelectedDays = function () {

                //I create a New moment since I always going to need the current date
                var momentJS = new moment();

                if (momentJS <= moment().add(4, 'days')) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    //Just disable the weekends
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    return day === 1 || day === 2 || day === 3 || day === 4 || day === 5;
                }
            }
```

this is my html

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Delivery date:</label>
                                <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
                                               md-date-filter="disableSelectedDays">
                                </md-datepicker>
                            </div>
```

this are the versions that I'm using
angular-maeria: v1.1.0-rc.5
datepicker: datepicker from angular material v1.1.0-rc4-master-88f2e3f

**EDIT 1**

I edited my code with your answer but now all the days in the datepicker are disabled I can't select anything, what I'm doing wrong?

I added this libaries moment libraries

moment.js version : 2.14.1
angular-moment https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, you can try using moment.js

To disable any number of days after the selected date, you can do this (Hopefully should work, have not tested, there might be typo's)

//date is the date you wanted to check

//NumberOfdays 4 as per your example

```
$scope.disableSelectedDays = function (date ) {
    if(date <= moment().add(4, 'days')) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
    //Just disable the weekends
            var day = date.getDay();
            return day === 1 || day === 2 || day ===3 || day === 4 || day === 5;
         }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what would be the 'days' value?, also  the date I want to check it's going to be always the current day I don't know why should I need to check it with the moment() date and if the current date is lesser than the moment day I'm adding 4 days? and that "date" variable it's the same that the "date.getDay()" variable thanks in advance

Comment: I edited my question @Natraj, now all my dates in the date picker are disabled why?

Comment: Also, seems you didn't use the code I've given you, you are comparing today with today itself and the loop goes on, that's the reason all the dates are disabled...

Comment: I believe the above code should work as expected if you pass the right **date**. With your example, if you pass **date** value is August 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, it will return **false** and for the rest of the week days it will return **true**.. Let me know if that doesn't work

Comment: ok thanks friend I would try and edit my question with the outcome